# How to get review tasks?

Tags: discussion, review

Reviewing is a fun thing. So I asked myself: Upon which parameters are review tasks assigned to specific users, ie. what must a user do to get more review tasks in his queue?

My guess is that some sort of activity is taken into account.

Best, 
Tom

Comment: are there per-person queues? My impression was that a task stayed in the queue until $n$ users had acted on it (5?) on a first-come-first-served basis.

Comment: You will be able to review suggested edits [when you reach 2k](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit). Review queues for [first posts and late answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) are available for users with 500 reputation points. I am not sure about close/reopen votes and low quality posts.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the system, but as I understood, those review queues are for every user (that has enough reputation). Does anybody know what the number of users $n$ is that is needed to approve any review? Also: Does every user get all the review tasks? My impression is no.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Close/Reopen is at 3k, and low quality posts is also at 2k. For those of us who have less than the required amount, it's listed whenever we go to the review page. (The privileges page also  has all of these except for LQP)